# Combining results of two select statements in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I am fairly new to SQL and I am using db2. I have the two below individual queries which on their own return expected results. However, I am looking to take the total from Query 2 divided by the result of Query 1.

Query 1:

```
select count(*) total
      from ltl400tst3.frp001
      JOIN ETLLIB.CYMD_TO_DATE
          ON fhpdat = cymd_date
      left join ltl400mod3.pup092
          on pcpro = fhpro
      left join LTL400MOD3.PUP090
          on PCNUM = PANUM and PCTID = PATID
      left join ltl400mod3.pup300 on pctid = cotid and pcnum = conum and pcline = coline and fhccd = coccd
      WHERE fhbtc in ('6A16579', '6R16579') and PASTAT != 'C' and DATE = '2021-09-01';
```

Query 2:

```
select Date, case cqtype when 'O' then 'Override' when 'S' then 'Alert' else 'Other' end record_type, count(*) total
      from LTL400MOD3.PUP301
      left join LTL400MOD3.PUP300
          on COTID = CQTID and CONUM = CQNUM and COLINE = CQLINE
      join ETLLIB.CYMD_TO_DATE
      on (CAST(CQRSSTMP AS DATE)) = DATE
      left join MASTER.ACCOUNT_HIERARCHY
          on COCCD = ACCOUNT
      where ((CQSACIID = '17') or (TOP_LEVEL_ACCOUNT = '0P16579')) and DATE = '2021-09-01'
group by date, CQTYPE;
```

My first thought was to use a CTE but I'm having some difficulty in formatting the expression to perform the function from multiple CTE's. Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Please qualify all columns with period denoted table names (i.e., `tablename.Date`) and mention *how* you want the two queries joined. Is there a calculation you need to run with the two totals?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a better way to achieve what you want, but since you didn't provide sample data, business logic, or expected output, I'll try to answer your exact question rather than attempt to refactor your queries.

```
with 
 query_1 (total) as (your_query_1_select_statement)

,query_2 (record_type, total) as  (your_query_2_select_statement)


select record_type, total/(select total from query_1) as ratio
from query_2;
```